# how do I set up dual monitors for desktop and laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-switch, docking-station, multiple-computers

I have a desktop computer and a laptop. I have dual monitors. The desktop has a graphics card with 2 DVI and 1 hdmi output tons of usb outs but no usb-c. The laptop has 1 hdmi and one thunderbolt 3 output. I would like to be able to switch from one to the other without having to unplug all the cables. Resolution is 1920x1080 @60hz and I dont really care if I get 4k at some point. Laptop is for work and desktop is for light gaming and my own personal software development projects. I have the following peripherals:

- 2x monitors with hdmi inputs
- usb mouse and keyboard
- external usb microphone
- external usb-c web cam
- external speakers usb powered / standard audio jack

I have a docking station for the laptop that handles all these (usbc thunderbolt connection to laptop, 2x hdmi out, 6 usb inputs, audio jack, usbc input) but have to manually unplug everything and plug into the desktop.

I am wondering if I should get a dual monitor KVM switch maybe? If I plug the desktop directly into the kvm switch (with 1 dvi to hdmi adapter) and the laptop docking station directly into the kvm switch what would that do to the quality of the laptops dual monitors (since it would be going through 2 switches before getting to the monitor)? Would I plug all the peripherals (mouse/keyboard/camera/speakers) into the kvm switch and somehow connect the kvm switch back to the docking station and desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bought a KVM switch (Greathtek GHT-S7212H2-U2 115$ from amazon) with 2 HDMI input and 4 HDMI outputs (for dual monitors). So far seems like its working. I had to get a converter for the webcam from USBC to USBA. I bought an DVI to HDMI converter for my computers second display output. I plug the laptop thunderbolt into the docking station which has 2 hdmi outputs and the docking station outputs into the KVM switch. Was worried the laptop display would not look good passing through 2 devices but seems ok so far. Doesnt seem to be any lag or other issue. Probably could have just gotten a cheaper usbc to dual hdmi out but I had the docking station already - really just using that dock for dual video now since the laptop only has one hdmi out.

KVM has 4 USB inputs for keyboard, mouse, webcam, microphone. No audio jack so planning on getting a cheap USB audio speaker. Have a wireless keyboard / mouse combo at the office which both feed into a single usb receiver. Planning on trying that to free up the 4th usb port on the KVM for a new USB speaker set. Not much room for expansion but dont think Ill add anything else ever.